# Pratiquer ou exercer ses compétences?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

Quel mot est plus agréable, plus utilisé ?

« Pratiquer ses compétences » ou « exercer ses competences » ?

Comment: Les deux se disent mais "exercer ses compétences" est beaucoup plus courant.

Comment: Les deux ont approximativement le même sens, tant que *pratiquer* n'est pas utilisé dans le sens *s'exercer* ou *tenter d'améliorer ses compétences*.

Answer (score 4):

"Exercer" me semble plus approprié.  Alternativement, je dirais "appliquer".

Answer (score 2):

En général, on *exerce* ses compétences. Je trouve « pratiquer ses compétences » étrange. Lorsque l'on utilise une aptitude pour accomplir une tâche, on exerce cette aptitude, on pratique l'activité qui consiste à accomplir cette tâche.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pratiquer+ses+comp%C3%A9tences%2Cexercer+ses+comp%C3%A9tences&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexercer%20ses%20comp%C3%A9tences%3B%2Cc0) considère le nombre d'occurrences de « pratiquer ses compétences » comme négligeable. Même si l'on trouve [quelquefois](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pratiquer%20ses%20comp%C3%A9tences%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr) cette dernière expression (l'occurrence la plus ancienne sur Google Books remontant à 2000), « exercer ses compétences » est [beaucoup plus courant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22exercer%20ses%20comp%C3%A9tences%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr).